# Minimum value of $\left(\frac{a-b}{b-c}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{b-c}{c-a}\right)^4+\left(\frac{c-a}{a-b}\right)^{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a,b,c \in R$ find the minimum value of $$E=\left(\frac{a-b}{b-c}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{b-c}{c-a}\right)^4+\left(\frac{c-a}{a-b}\right)^{4}$$
My attempt:
Let $x=a-b,y=b-c,z=c-a$

So $x+y+z=0$

We need to minimize $$E=\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{4}$$
$\implies$
$$E=\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{x+y}{x}\right)^4$$
Letting $\frac{x}{y}=t$ we get:
$$E=t^4+\frac{1}{(t+1)^4}+\frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}$$
Now i tried using derivatives, but very tedious.

Comment: Finding the minimum values of $E(t)$ boils down to finding its values at the three real roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of the polynomial $$p(t)=t^9+3t^8+t^7-3t^6+t^5+2t^4-10t^3-13t^2-6t-1,$$ according to [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E4%2B1%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E4%2B%28x%2B1%29%5E4%2Fx%5E4%29%27)

Comment: There are three real and six complex roots.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Define
$$
x={a-b\over b-c}\quad,\quad y={b-c\over c-a}\quad,\quad z={c-a\over a-b}
$$
and try to minimize $x^4+y^4+z^4$ constrained to $xyz=1$.

Alternatively, you can also define
$$
x=\ln\left|{a-b\over b-c}\right|\quad,\quad y=\ln\left|{b-c\over c-a}\right|\quad,\quad z=\ln\left|{c-a\over a-b}\right|
$$
and minimize $e^{4x}+e^{4y}+e^{4z}$ constrained to $x+y+z=0$.

**Edit**

Thanks to @RiverLi's comment below, also three more constraints should be included:
$$
{y(x+1)+1=0
\\
z(y+1)+1=0
\\
x(z+1)+1=0
}
$$

Comment: To minimize $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ constrained to $xyz=1$ seems incorrect. The reason is that if you let $x={a-b\over b-c}\quad,\quad y={b-c\over c-a}\quad,\quad z={c-a\over a-b}$, we have $xyz = 1$, $xy + y + 1 = 0$, however, you only keep $xyz=1$ and ignore the other.

Comment: @RiverLi, thank you for that observation, I made an edit.

Comment: Actually, $xyz = 1$ and $xy + y + 1 = 0$ implies $z(y+1)+1 = 0$ and $x(z+1) + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

My second solution (using derivative):

Since $\lim_{t\to \infty} E(t) = \infty$, $\lim_{t\to - \infty} E(t) = \infty$,
$\lim_{t\to 0} E(t) = \infty$ and $\lim_{t\to -1} E(t) = \infty$, the minimum of $E(t)$
is attained at the points with $E'(t) = 0$.

We have
\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 
\frac{4(t^2+t+1)^2}{(t+1)^5t^5}(t^9+3t^8+t^7-3t^6+t^5+2t^4-10t^3-13t^2-6t-1)\\
&= \frac{4(t^2+t+1)^2}{(t+1)^5t^5}F(t)[t^3+(c+3)t^2+ct-1]
\end{align}
where
$$c = -\frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{108+12\sqrt{849}} + \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{-108 + 12\sqrt{849}}-2,$$
and
\begin{align}
F(t) &= t^6-ct^5+(c+1)^2 t^4+(-c^3-4c^2-7c-5)t^3\\
&\quad +(c^2+3c+4)^2t^2+(-c^5-8c^4-31c^3-67c^2-81c-45)t+1.
\end{align}

It is not difficult to prove that $F(t) > 0$ for all $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Thus, all real roots of $E'(t) = 0$ are the real roots of $t^3+(c+3)t^2+ct-1 = 0$.

By using $t^3+(c+3)t^2+ct-1 = 0$, we have
\begin{align}
E(t) &= \frac{t^8(t+1)^4+t^4+(t+1)^8}{(t+1)^4t^4}\\
&= \frac{\mathrm{rem}(t^8(t+1)^4+t^4+(t+1)^8,\ t^3+(c+3)t^2+ct-1)}{\mathrm{rem}((t+1)^4t^4,\ t^3+(c+3)t^2+ct-1)}\\
&= c^4+8c^3+32c^2+68c+69\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 + 3396\sqrt{849}}
+ \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 - 3396\sqrt{849}} + \frac{7}{3}
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{rem}(p(x),q(x))$ is the remainder of $p(x)$ divided by $q(x)$ for two polynomials $p(x), q(x)$.

Thus, the minimum of $E = E(t) = t^4 + \frac{1}{(t+1)^4} + \frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}, \ t \ne 0, -1$ is given by
$$E_{\min} = \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 + 3396\sqrt{849}}
+ \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 - 3396\sqrt{849}} + \frac{7}{3}.$$
Note: $E_{\min} \approx 12.5037895937134016209875697987512$.

Comment: Wow, I never thought there would be a closed form for that! very nice (+1)

Comment: @clathratus Thanks. Let $f = E(t) - y$ and $g = (t+1)^4t^4f$. Then $\mathrm{resultant}(g, E'(t), t)$ which gives $y^3-7y^2+3y-898 = 0$ where $\mathrm{resultant}$ denotes the resultant of two polynomials. This means the minimum is a real root of $y^3-7y^2+3y-898 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We assume $a\ne b\ne c$.
We see that if $$E(t)=t^4+\frac{1}{(t+1)^4}+\frac{(t+1)}{t^4},$$
then
$$E'(t)=4\frac{(t^2+t+1)^2}{t^5(t+1)^5}p(t),$$
where $$p(t)=t^9+3t^8+t^7-3t^6+t^5+2t^4-10t^3-13t^2-6t-1.$$
From our assumption that $a\ne b\ne c$, we have that $t=\frac{a-b}{b-c}\not\in\{0,-1\}$, and since $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$, $t^2+t+1\ne0$. Thus the critical points of $E(t)$ are the real roots of $p(t)$. There are only three real roots of $p(t)$. Call them $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, with $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$. We have
$$\begin{align}
\alpha&\approx -1.7212312143130658672\\
\beta&\approx -0.41902052920932262495\\
\gamma&\approx 1.3865179156901112246.
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
E(\alpha)&\approx 12.5037895937134016209875697987512072072\color{red}{22979907033168192287594834}\\
E(\beta)&\approx 12.5037895937134016209875697987512072072\color{green}{14601727355467488179851200}\\
E(\gamma)&\approx 12.5037895937134016209875697987512072072\color{blue}{10427320909272240776493390}.
\end{align}$$
Thus it appears as if $E(\alpha)\ge E(\beta)\ge E(\gamma)>12+\frac{10803682224985055382}{21444830063582275811}$, so that
$$\left(\frac{a-b}{b-c}\right)^4+\left(\frac{b-c}{c-a}\right)^4+\left(\frac{c-a}{a-b}\right)^4>12+\frac{10803682224985055382}{21444830063582275811}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The minimum of $E = E(t) = t^4 + \frac{1}{(t+1)^4} + \frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}, \ t \ne 0, -1$ admits a closed form:
$$E_{\min} = \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 + 3396\sqrt{849}}
+ \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 - 3396\sqrt{849}} + \frac{7}{3}.$$
Note: $E_{\min} \approx 12.5037895937134016209875697987512$.

*Proof*: Denote
$$Q = \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 + 3396\sqrt{849}}
+ \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{98972 - 3396\sqrt{849}} + \frac{7}{3}.$$
We have
$$Q^3-7Q^2+3Q-898 = 0, \quad Q-7 > 0, \quad Q^2 - 7Q + 3 > 0. \tag{1}$$

We have
\begin{align}
&[E^2 + (Q-7)E + Q^2-7Q+3](E - Q)\\
=\ & E^3 - 7E^2 + 3E - Q^3 + 7Q^2 - 3Q\\
=\ & E^3 - 7E^2 + 3E - 898\\
=\ & \left(t^4 + \frac{1}{(t+1)^4} + \frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}\right)^3 - 7\left(t^4 + \frac{1}{(t+1)^4} + \frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}\right)^2\\
&\qquad  + 
3\left(t^4 + \frac{1}{(t+1)^4} + \frac{(t+1)^4}{t^4}\right) - 898\\
=\ & \frac{1}{(t+1)^{12}t^{12}}f(t)[g(t)]^2\\
\ge\ & 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
f(t) &= t^{18} + 6 t^{17} + 19 t^{16} + 40 t^{15} + 57 t^{14} + 60 t^{13} + 93 t^{12} + 308 t^{11}\\
 &\quad + 901 t^{10} + 1832 t^9 + 2650 t^8 + 2836 t^7 + 2316 t^6 + 1466 t^5\\
 &\quad + 717 t^4 + 264 t^3 + 70 t^2 + 12 t + 1, \\
g(t) &= t^9 + 3t^8 + t^7 - 3t^6 + t^5 + 2t^4 - 10t^3 - 13t^2 - 6t - 1,
\end{align}
and it is not difficult to prove that $f(t) > 0$ for all $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $E^2 + (Q-7)E + Q^2-7Q+3 > 0$, from (2), we have $E \ge Q$.
Also, $g(t) = 0$ has at least one real root, and thus the minimum of $E$ is exactly equal to $Q$. We are done.